# Returning pointer to a class field in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust

I am trying to return a pointer to one of the class fields with one function in order to not create a copy of the object and be able to edit them outside of the function. The field is a vector of a certain struct that I have created and has the name `packets`.

The function that I have created is the following but already the IDE is prompting an error before compiling:

```
    pub fn get_packets(&mut self) -> *Vec<point::Point>::const {
        &self.packets
    }
```

I have been checking by adding const, mut, or others at the beginning and end of the return class, but there is no good result for now. Clearly, I do not know what I am doing, so I kindly ask for a bit of aid.

Comment: 1. please read, and post, errors you get from the compiler, while its suggestions are not always useful its messages tend to be clear and to the point. 2. please post minimal reproducible examples, stackoverflow still does not pay for mind reading and other extrasensory powers, and guessing is complicated. 3. what little code you posted here is straight up not syntactically valid, have you considered fixing it? `*T` is not a valid Rust type, and AFAIK associated types are only supported on traits, since `Vec` is a concrete type that means `Vec<T>::U` can't be valid either.

Comment: Best as I can say your snippet should be something along the lines of `pub fn get_packets(&self) -> &Vec<???> { &self.packets }`, or `pub fn get_packets(&self) -> &[???] { &self.packets }`.

Comment: Please read [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Comment: @OptimisticPeach, that literally solved it, to be honest. I will write a solution for it on how the problem was solved. But it was pretty interesting reading on memory management.

Answer (score 2):

You are using non-existing syntax. Try either:

```rust
pub fn get_packets(&self) -> &Vec<point::Point> {
    &self.packets
}
```

or

```rust
pub fn get_packets_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<point::Point> {
    &mut self.packets
}
```

It is common in Rust to provide two methods for getting a *reference* to a field. One to get a shared one, and one to get an exclusive/mutable one.

Also you could hide implementation details in the `get_packets` version by returning `&[point::Point]`.